# Custom Recent Post In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want make custom recent post. In standard condition, the widget just show every newest post. But how to make recent post with condition, 4 newest post is disappear and start showing post from 5th posts.

illustration:

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* newest post  | D

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* 2nd new post | D

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* 3rd new post | D

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* 4th new post | D

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* 5th new post | SS

Note:

D: Disappear | SS: Start showing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please specify your question a bit more? I have no clue what you're talking about, to be honest.

Comment: Ok @vdwijngaert, I mean, I just want showing the post from 5th, so the newest post temporary disappear because I don't want 4 newest post showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the offset parameter of WP_Query

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 4 ) );
```

This returns 5 posts after the 4 newest posts.